# Is the ";" a must always?

Tags: javascript

I always doubt if the ";" is a must after I call a function?

```
list.innerHTML += '<h4 id="title">' + trimmed(data.results[i].title); + '</h4>
<span class="main-color">Action, Sci-Fi</span>';
```

Comment: Well the semicolon is at the wrong place....It goes at the end of the line, not randomly in the middle.

Comment: You always doubt but never tried?

Comment: My bad, let me edit my question so you can see the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;` goes between *statements*, not after function calls. If you put it in the middle of an expression, it will break that statement into two statements, and almost certainly won't do what you intend. If the above is part of a variable assignment, `</h4>` won't be included in the result, because the `;` takes `+ '</h4>` out of the concatenation and makes it a separate statement of its own (which doesn't do anything).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me.